# Change store view automatically for different customer groups in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, handler, store

I'm currently using Magento 2.3.2 and I would like to show certain customers a specific store view based on their customer group. (For example a customer in the "General" group would see the default store view, while a customer in the "Platinum" group would see the "Platinum" store view with a slightly different logo and design).

Is there an extension out there that can do this? I can only find ones which restrict the products in the catalog?

**Edit 20/02/2020 -**

Thanks to [Invigorate Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9019169/invigorate-systems) for the solution. I have now implemented the code as below in the app > code folders:

> **registration.php** file inside **GroupSite/SiteSwitch/**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'GroupSite_SiteSwitch',
    __DIR__
    );
```

> **module.xml** file inside **GroupSite/SiteSwitch/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="GroupSite_SiteSwitch" setup_version="2.1.1"></module>
</config>
```

> **events.xml** inside **GroupSite/SiteSwitch/etc/frontend/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_layout_handles" instance="GroupSite\SiteSwitch\Observer\AddHandles" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **AddHandles.php** file inside **GroupSite/SiteSwitch/Observer**

```
<?php

namespace GroupSite\SiteSwitch\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
         if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
             {
             $customerGroup = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
                if($customerGroup === '5'){
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('13'); //Set your desired store ID that you wish to set.
                }
                else{
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('1');         
                }
             }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using Observers, here's an example module for you. this module will change store ID after customer login to the system.

> 1. Create **registration.php** file inside **Vendor/Module/**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
    );
```

> 2. Create **module.xml** file inside **Vendor/Module/etc/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.1.1"></module>
</config>
```

> 3. Create **events.xml** inside **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_layout_handles" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddHandles" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> 4. Create Handler file for Observer **AddHandles.php** file inside **Vendor/Module/Observer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            /*
            Here you fetch loggedIn Customer Group and add if condition such as
            if(customerGroup == 'ID/Name of group you desire'){
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('2'); //Set your desired store ID that you wish to set.
            }
            */
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('2');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Hi. I'm getting an error when I upload the code do you know what might be causing this?

Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The XML in file "/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml" is invalid: Element 'config', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed. Line: 2 Verify the XML and try again.

Thanks

Comment: Did you change Vendor and Module name wherever needed ? Also please do edit question with your complete code which brings you above error. I would love to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi. I've figured out what was wrong (XMLSchema-instance) in events.xml needed a hyphen in it. Unfortunately I'm now getting a new error. I've updated the question with this.

Comment: Delete the comment from AddHandles.php and check. Delete /*
            Here you fetch loggedIn Customer Group and add if condition such as
            if(customerGroup == 'ID/Name of group you desire'){
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('2'); //Set your desired store ID that you wish to set.
            }
            */

Comment: You need to remove if condition with customerGroup as well.Just keep this :  if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
{
    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('2');
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208184/discussion-between-invigorate-systems-and-cjnotts).

Comment: Hi. Got this working now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you, :)